# 404 redirect instead of internal route

Tags: redirect, 404-page, 404

Currently when I hit a 404 URL Magento serves the custom 404 page I set up under CMS -> Sites (noRoute) while staying at the 404 URL.

What I want is that instead Magento should redirect to the page www.mydomain.de/404.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the reroute action in your own module and then, inside the controller code, have:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
die;
```

That should do the job.

Here is a tutorial on extending the reroute action:

https://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/magento-cms-controller-override-noroute-method-modify/